# 'class' attribute is not declared

Tags: c#, visual-studio, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to integrate google maps to Xamarin.Android, however, the **class** gets highlighted and mentions that its not declared. How do I declare it?

I have already went to **http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android** to add its attribute there as **xs:attribute name='class' type='xs:string' />**, but still highlights on class as shown below.

[Undeclared class attribute screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYYY8.png)

Your help is appreciated. Thank you in advanced,

Regards, 
Xamarin and Programming Newbie

Comment: 2 suggestions, first try putting class in the first line, e.g. `<fragment class="..."`. It may/may not be the difference. Second, since its just a warning and not an error, try to compile and run the project once to see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 'class' attribute is not declared

The problem is that the Intellisense could not pick the attributes you type although  those attributes did exists in android SDK. So the Visual Studio shows that :

```
The 'class' attribute is not declared
```

As Keyur PATEL said,  it's just a warning and not an error, you could compile without any problem.

**Solution :**

There are some files are missing in XML schema folder in Visual Studio, so download these files links given below :

- https://github.com/atsushieno/monodroid-schema-gen/blob/master/android-layout-xml.xsd
- https://github.com/atsushieno/monodroid-schema-gen/blob/master/schemas.android.com.apk.res.android.xsd

You need download and move these file manually to :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\XML\Schemas\1033
```

[image]

This error will be gone, effect like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8Xcy.png).